# Weird output when summing 1<<2 and 1<<3 in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence

So I was just trying some bit manipulation in C++. Here is what I tried:

```
int a = 1<<2;
cout<<a;
```

This gives the output as `4`.

```
int a = 1<<3;
cout<<a;
```

This gives the output as `8`

But when I do:

```
int a = 1<<2 + 1<<3;
cout<<a;
```

It gives the output as `64`. Why so?

I also tried:

```
int a = 1<<2;
int b = 1<<3;
cout<<a + b;
```

Which gives the output as `12` as expected.

Comment: `<<` has lower precedence than `+`, `1<<2 + 1<<3` = `1<<(2 + 1)<<3`

Comment: It's because `1<<2 + 1<<3` is really `1<<  2+1  <<3`. Don't be misled by whitespace.

Comment: As a general rule, use brackets in such cases. They may not always be necessary, but they increase readability and reduce the risk of such errors. Moreover, you won't need to learn every case of operator precedence by heart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because addition has a higher operator precedence than bitshift. In other words, your second example is equivalent to `1 << (2 + 1) << 3`

Furthermore, since bitshifting is left-associative, it's the same as `(1 << (2 + 1)) << 3`. This simplifies to `8 << 3`, which is `64`.

Answer (score 6):

It's about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

`+` has higher precedence than shift operators, therefore `1<<2 + 1<<3` is done as `1 << (2 + 1) << 3` which is similar to `1 << 6 == 64` (since `<<` is [left-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), as you can see in the precedence table in the link above)

That's also why `cout<<a + b;` works, because it's parsed as `cout<<(a + b);`, otherwise you'll get some errors like *"can't add a number to a stream"*

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator has a higher precedence than `<<` operator, so here's that line is being evaluated:

```cpp
int a = (1<<(2 + 1))<<3;
```

You should group it like this with parentheses:

```cpp
int a = (1<<2) + (1<<3);
```