# Using bitwise operation to multiply by 3

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Very basic question that is tripping me up:
Write a function that produces the same thing as this:

```
int mult_3_div_4(int x){return (x*3)/4;}
```

But only using ! ~ & + << >> bitwise operators

Divide by 4 is of course << 2
So I tried something like:

`int test(int x) {return ((x<<1 + x) >> 2);}`

But I can't seem to find anything that matches x*3 using bitwise operators

Comment: `(x<<1 + x)` is really `(x << 1+x)`

Comment: Check operator precedence and use of parentheses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird output when summing 1<<2 and 1<<3 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354730/weird-output-when-summing-12-and-13-in-c)

Comment: `x*3` is `x+x+x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bitwise shifts `<<` `>>` have lower precedence that binary operators `+` `-`.

So the line should be...

```
int test(int x) {return ((x<<1) + x) >> 2;}
```

Comment: Basically, the left shift operator does multiplications of left operand into 2 powers of right operand. so here, the value you are getting is 2^1 = 2 .Similarly, the right shift operator does divisions of 2 powers. With this information, do understand this answer.

Comment: Alternative for style points: `return (n>>1)+(n>>2);` which is _n/2 + n/4_ = _2n/4 + n/4_ = _3n/4_

Comment: @5andr0 That alternative fails for any `n&3==3`, because you didn't consider the bit carry that could happen during addition.

Comment: @syockit Thanks for pointing that out! You just fixed an Off-by-one buffer overflow in my production code